# Access Entity in configureActions - Easyadmin 4 with Symfony 7

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

i want to create an action link with the following code in my CompanyCrudController (configureFilters function):

```
$urlDomains = $this->adminUrlGenerator
        ->setController(DomainCrudController::class)
        ->setAction(Action::INDEX)
        ->set('filters[company][comparison]', '=')
        ->set('filters[company][value]', '1')
        ->generateUrl();
```

With this code I am redirected to the DomainCrudController and, among other things, the filter for the company is set (here value = 1).
Now the value for the company should be automatically set to the respective EntityID.

**How i get the entity in the configureActions() method?**